# Execute command and print variable in batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I've got a batch script that sets an environment variable- it's intended that you run the thing and then run extra commands from there.
Instead I simply need to print the values of the environment variables, without changing the environmnet of the caller.
I've tried e.g. `mybat.bat && echo %VAR%` but it seems that
a) the value infects the caller and
b) it only works if you run it repeatedly- presumably something to do with the environment reading the VAR before executing the batch script.

Any suggestions?

Comment: In `mybat.bat` write them to a file, e.g. `(Echo %%Var1%%=%Var1%&Echo %%Var2%%=%Var2%)>File.txt` then read them in the new script, e.g. `Type File.txt`.

Comment: If you wanted to run that from the command line you would have to do this. `cmd /V:on /C "mybat.bat && echo !VAR!"`

Comment: I don't control mybat, so can't simply change it to be sane, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You need `enabledelayedexpansion` do `cmd /?` and you will see:

> /V:ON   Enable delayed environment variable expansion using ! as the
>           delimiter. For example, /V:ON would allow !var! to expand the
>           variable var at execution time.  The var syntax expands variables
>           at input time, which is quite a different thing when inside of a FOR
>           loop.

In a batch we would typically use this this to expand on execution time. You want to run it from cmdline and therefore need to enable it using the `/V:ON` switch and replace your `%` for `!`

```
cmd /V:ON mybat.cmd && echo !VAR!
```

Also, there are minor differences between `.bat` and `.cmd` file extensions when it gets to resetting of `errorlevel` but I suggest you use the `.cmd` extension instead for that reason at least.

Answer (score 0):

Variables are usually set local to the running `cmd.exe` session, so in order not to 'infect the caller' you need to run the script in a different `cmd.exe` session.

This uses `Set` to show the variable and value

```bat
Cmd /C "MyBat & Set VAR"
```

If you wish only to see the value you can use `Echo`:

- …Using delayed expansion:

  ```bat
  Cmd /V:On /C "MyBat & Echo(!VAR!"
  ```
- …Using `Call` to force expansion:

  ```bat
  Cmd /C "MyBat & Call Echo(%VAR%"
  ```

  *Note* to run this from a batch file you'd need to double the **`%`** characters, i.e. `%%VAR%%`.